# Javascript - alternative for window.onload when loading code asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I have a calculator I'm integrating into my site. Normally, when on a page by itself, the calculator initializes with the following function

```
window.onload = function () {

/* Initializes calculator */

}
```

However, I'm loading this calculator to the page asynchronously when the user asks for it, and it's not on the page by default. How do I initialize the calculator once it's loaded onto the page asynchronously? The problem I have is that the `window.onload = function ()` which initializes the calculator doesn't work when I load the calculator to the page asynchronously, since the `window.onload` event has already occurred. What function should I use instead of `window.onload` to initialize the calculator when it's brought to the page asynchronously?

```
// 1. Page loads
// 2. Calculator is brought to page asynchronously 
// 3. Code below executes to initialize the calculator

***something else*** = function () {

/* Initializes calculator */

}
```

Comment: How do you load the calculator? There certainly is a callback to that load.

Comment: This depends on the method you are using to bring the calculator "_to the page asynchronously_".

Comment: I'm using an ajax call to a PHP file which loads the HTML/CSS/JS for the calculator

Comment: Avoid `onload`, always prefer `addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: You may have focussed too much on the `minimal` and not enough on the `reproducible` aspect of a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ;)

Comment: Your calculator code, if loaded dynamically, will run at the moment it's loaded.  Where you have `***something else*** = function...` try simply `console.log("I got loaded");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **anonymous function** assigned to `onload` from this...

```
window.onload = function() {
    // stuff
};
```

...to a **named function** that's invoked directly or indirectly [based on `document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState), like this:

```
function initCalculator() {
    // stuff
}

if( document.readyState === 'loading' ) {
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initCalculator );
}
else if( document.readyState === 'interactive' || document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    initCalculator ();
}
```

---

- If the `<script>` is part of the normal (static) HTML's `<head>` and loaded synchronously or uses `defer` then the  `initCalculator` function will run when `'DOMContentLoaded'` fires.
- If the `<script>` is part of the normal (static) HTML's `<head>` with `async` - or the `<script>` was added after the page was loaded then the `initCalculator` function will run immediately if the async script was loaded after the `DOMContentLoaded`, or if it loads before `DOMContentLoaded` then it will run as appropriate.

---

To be extra-safe, you can prevent double-initialization by using a `dataset` entry on `<html>` (this is safer than adding a property on `window`):

```
function initCalculator() {
    if( document.documentElement.dataset['calcLoaded'] === 'true' ) return;
    
    // do stuff

    document.documentElement.dataset['calcLoaded'] = 'true';
}

if( document.readyState === 'loading' ) {
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initCalculator );
}
else if( document.readyState === 'interactive' || document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    initCalculator ();
}
```